# Not able to highlight selected items in custom-ng-select

Tags: angularjs, angular-reactive-forms, angular-ngselect

I created a custom ng-select with reactive form and imagine a list of data passed as dataList.

I have some default values from API to show them as selected but not able to do so. Items get's displayed in the ng-select input field but in the listing it does not make them as selected item.

[image]

**Issue is not with the styles**, everything is correct, because when i select item manually from list it works fine.

**custom-select.component.html**

```
<div [formGroup]="componentFormGroup">
  <ng-select
    class="select-dropdown"
    [items]="dataList"
    [bindLabel]="name"
    [bindValue]="id"
    [multiple]="true"
    [placeholder]="placeHolder"
    [formControlName]="componentFormControlName"
    (change)="onSelectChange($event)">
    <ng-template
      ng-label-tmp
      let-item="item"
      let-clear="clear"
      class="template-user">
      <div class="selected-items pr-1">
        <span class="ng-value-label label-name">
          {{ item.name }}
        </span>

        <span
          class="ng-value-icon right cross-icon"
          (click)="clear(item)"
          aria-hidden="true" >
          ×
        </span>
      </div>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item" let-index="index" let-item$="item$">
      {{ item.id }} {{ item.name }}
    </ng-template>
  </ng-select>
</div>
```

**custom-select.ts**

```
this.dataList = [
  {id: 17, name: Ahsan Shah}, {id: 28, name: John Doe}, {id: 25, name: Muhammad Yousuf}
]

// wait & get default data from API and assign it to a variable
this.defaultListData = defaultResponse?.resources; // sample [{id: 25, name: Muhammad Yousuf}]

// then assign value to form group
this.componentFormGroup.controls[this.componentFormControlName].setValue(this.defaultListData);
```

What i am doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @imMoazzamAli!
Have you resolved your issue?
I had the same issue with a custom template as options, and made them selected and highlighted - this is unusual.

Comment: Maybe I have some options how to solve this issue.

In my case, it's already worked